# Ubuntu Pro 22.04 AMI not available?

Tags: 22.04, aws

We currently build a golden image from the Ubuntu 22.04 AMI offered from Canonical, however there are security patches that are only available through Ubuntu Pro. In researching creating an AMI from the Ubuntu Pro AMI I discovered that there is not currently an AMI available for 22.04 on AMD. There is a Real-Time Kernel version for ARM but that is not an option for us.

The Ubuntu Pro [page](https://ubuntu.com/aws/pro) on ubuntu.com lists 22.04 as an option with a link to the AMI listing in AWS, but this hits a 404.

Does anyone know what's happening with this missing Pro AMI? We cannot roll back to 20.04, so this is prevent us from patching what corporate is calling a Sev 5 security vulnerability.

Thank you

<Edit> The Golden image that we build based off of the 22.04 AMI is an automated build via a scheduled pipeline. There is a process for using the Ubuntu Pro AMIs where we can build our golden image and incorporate the Pro subscription into it. This either isn't possible or would require additional engineering to get it working with the non-pro AMI.

I'm aware that there is a 22.04 LTS AMI available, as that is what we are currently using. We need the Pro subscription so that we can patch security vulnerabilities because only Pro has those patches available.

Comment: The page you referenced doesn't include an option for 22.04

Comment: Scroll all the way down. There's a link for 22.04 Ubuntu Pro in AWS

Comment: Are you looking for https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ and make sure you change the version column to match 22.04?

Comment: Yes. There is a 22.04 LTS AMI but it does not have the Pro subscription as part of its configuration.

Comment: "there are security patches that are only available through Ubuntu Pro." I doubt that. Yes, there are but those are ONLY for Ubuntu Pro software so NA for not Pro systems.

Comment: Fair enough. What I should have said is that the patch is only available for the version of the software that we're currently pinned to via pro.


But this is a detail. Why is there no 22.04 Pro AMI available when there is a 14.04 Pro AMI? A ten year old version has Pro and a two year old version doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you still have the issue and for anyone looking for the same:

Ubuntu Pro 22.04 is not listed on AWS Marketplace because it is available on the AWS EC2 Quick Launch menu.

Also, you can always search for any version using AWSCLI.

We have covered this in the [following post](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-deploy-ubuntu-pro-in-aws-in-2023/23367)

Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer. I worked with Carlos last week on this.